# Copy venv to an offline pc

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv, pyvenv

How can I migrate my python virtual environment to an offline pc?

Comment: I take it that by "offline" you mean "no network access" ?

Comment: Copy the venv directory to a USB stick, then copy it to the offline PC. Not hard...

Comment: No network access @ OneCricketeer

Comment: @MattDMo, it doesnt work